# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated(Apache-coyote/1.1)

Tags: authentication, peer

I want to use Rest API to create/modify work item in java program.
My server is Apache-coyote/1.1.

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    JSONObject JSONobj = new JSONObject();
    System.out.println("hello ");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json  ");
    post.setHeader("xyz","abcd");   //userid and password

    StringEntity input = new StringEntity(JSONobj.toString());

    System.out.println("hello ");
    post.setEntity(input);
    System.out.println("hello ");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

[image]